# What is wrong with this SQL statement for inserting concatenated IDS from a table into a field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
INSERT INTO Activity_Feed (userID,Type,DataIDs,PodID) 
VALUES ( 1437
      , 'eventattend'
      , (SELECT LEFT(EventID, LEN(eventID) - 1 as nvarchar) 
         FROM ( 
            SELECT EventiD + ', ' 
            FROM   events 
            FOR XML PATH ('')) c (EventID))
      , 5)
```

Basically I want to take a bunch of IDs from a table and insert them as a comma delimited string into a varchar field.

E.g.

```
Activity_Feed (table)

activityID   1
userID       2
DataIDs      1,3,4,56,367 // This would be the (Select Ids FROM bit)
```

I want to take a bunch of RSVP IDs from a table and stick their IDs in the field...

To further explain I wanted to avoid normalizing the query because of the nature of this query. Let me know if I should still separate out the data...

The activity feed works like this...

I create a new entry in activity with a type of `event_attending` (which is an event I am attending.

I timestamp it, I enter the ID for the event in the `dataIDs` field any new activity matching `event_attending` in a 6 hour period fires an `update` record rather than `insert`

I keep the timestamp the same but update the ID's that are associated with that time period so basically update the IDs with the latest event attendance within that time period.

I thought normalizing seemed like overkill :D is there such thing as overkill with normalization?

Comment: Don't do that. Normalize your DB

Comment: Format your posts so that your queries are readable.

Comment: Never insert comma separated values into a column. You are just making them harder to retrieve later.

Comment: Please see [Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: I've updated the question but now see your points. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always normalize your database.

This is *totally not* wrong but very poor in database design.

Reasons why this is very poor:

- hard to join  tables
- hard to find values

Why not create table like this,

Activity

- ActivityID
- ActivityName

Feed

- FeedID
- FeedName

Activity_Feed

- FeedID
- ActivityID

so `Activity_Feed` table will contain something like this

```
FeedID  ActivityID
=====================
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         1
2         3
3         2
3         1
```

and you can now join the tables,

```
SELECT  a.ActivityName, c.FeedName
FROM    Activity a
        INNER JOIN Activity_Feed b
            ON a.ActivityID = b.ActivityID
        INNER JOIN Feed c
            ON b.FeedID = c.FeedID
-- WHERE  a.ActivityName = 1             -- or something like this
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I will accept this as the answer as I now realise the benefits of normalizing the data rather than trying to bodge stuff and validate it later!

Comment: Could you recommend some database logic for this for me in your answer? It would really help. 

I was going to just create another table called activity_items which will then add in items for that time period. :)

Comment: @ChrisDowdeswell updated the answer with proposed schema :D and sample query.